# Set up DNS name servers for WP Engine

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver, dns-servers, cname

I have set up my blog on WP Engine, and have been given a CNAME. My domain name is registered with CrazyDomains, and currently the name servers are pointing to Linode servers (where the blog was hosted previously). What do I need to do so that my domain name points to the blog on WP Engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoops - misread your original question - take 2: According to my co-worker Mike Price -you need to switch your nameservers to crazydomains default ones to change your A record and your A record should point to the IP in the WP Engine User Portal. Then add to domains page in the WP engine User Portal. Finally, Change home/site URL 2. Also, You can also change CNAME instead of A record but still need to change NameServer back to crazydomains. Hope this helps!

Disclosure: I am a WP Engine employee

Comment: I"ve tried this, but still doesn't seem to be working. Possibly an issue on the CrazyDomains side. I'll contact support and post an update here...

Comment: Issue resolved after registrar removed web forwarding